# If $M\subset \mathbb{R^n}$ and $M \cap Bd(M) = \emptyset$, then $int(M)=\emptyset $?

Tags: general-topology

I tried to solve this task here:

> If $M\subset\mathbb{R^n}$ and $M\cap Bd (M)=\emptyset$, then M is open. (Bd(M) is the set of all boundary points of M)

Well I know how to solve this task though. But while I was trying to solve it, I encountered a problem leading to a contradiction. And I don't know where the mistake is.

I wrote $$ M \cap Bd(M)=\emptyset \implies M^c \cup Bd(M)^c=\mathbb{R^n} \implies \overline{M^c}=\mathbb{R^n}\implies \mathbb{R^n}\setminus \overline{M^c}=\emptyset \implies int(M)=\emptyset$$

But this is impossible since M should be open, so int(M) can't be empty right? So where is the mistake?

Is there anyone who could help me out? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your second implication you used the (incorrect) identity $Bd(M)^c = Bd(M^c)$. To see that this is wrong, consider e.g. $M = (0,\infty)$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $Bd(M)^c = \{0\}^c = \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$, and $0 \in M^c$, so indeed $M^c \cup Bd(M)^c = \mathbb{R}^n$. But it is not true that $\overline{M^c} = \mathbb{R}^n$.